# How to reload async data into controller scope on route refresh?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular1.6

I have a service function that I need to call each time a route is visited or refreshed. The function returns an Angular promise. The result of the promise needs to be loaded into the controller's scope each time the function is called.

I'm currently using a resolve argument on the state definition to call the function.

```
.state('app.theState', {
  url: '/theRoute/:theRouteId',
  views: {
      'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/theRoute.html',
          controller: 'TheRouteCtrl'
      }
  },
  resolve: {theResolvedResult: function(theService){
             return theService.theAsyncCall().then(function(result){
                return result;
              },function(errMsg){
                return errMsg;
              });}
})
```

The data is passed into the controller as an argument.

```
.controller( 'TheRouteCtrl', function($scope, $state, $log, theResolvedResult)
```

I am updating the controller $scope in a watch on the global that holds theResolvedResult. (Using the [workaround](http://plnkr.co/edit/DVFG8T?p=preview) described at the end of this [post](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c)). I tried a watch on the argument itself, but it never gets triggered.

```
$scope.$state=$state;
$scope.$watch('$state.$current.locals.globals.theResolvedResult', function (result) {
  $scope.aValue = result.aValue;
});
```

Unfortunately, I guess because the watch is on a global, the watch is triggered when *any* route runs, and all other routes throw an error for every route except the one where the resolve is defined.

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'aValue' of undefined
at route_ctrl.js:234
```

How can I fix these errors, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just guard against the case where `result` is not defined:

```
$scope.$watch('$state.$current.locals.globals.theResolvedResult', function (result) {
  if (result) {
    $scope.aValue = result.aValue;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good pragmatic workaround. I'd still like to get a solution that only runs the watches for the current controller, to eliminate the wasteful checking and also not hide errors when the result should be defined and isn't. So I'll leave the question open for a while.

Answer (score 0):

### Breaking change for Angular V1.6

### Move initialization logic into `$onInit` function

```
/* REPLACE
$scope.$state=$state;
$scope.$watch('$state.$current.locals.globals.theResolvedResult', function (result) {
  $scope.aValue = result.aValue;
});
*/

//WITH
this.$onInit = function() {
    $scope.aValue = $state.$current.locals.globals.theResolvedResult.aValue;
};
```

> Initialization logic that relies on bindings being present should be put in the controller's `$onInit()` method, which is guaranteed to always be called after the bindings have been assigned.
>
> [— AngularJS Migration Guide (V1.6 $compile breaking change bcd0d4)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-bcd0d4)

---

---

#### Erroneous rejection handler

The resolve is converting a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise:

```
/* ERRONEOUS
resolve: {theResolvedResult: function(theService){
         return theService.theAsyncCall().then(function(result){
            return result;
          },function(errMsg){
            //ERRONEOUS converts rejection
            return errMsg;
          });}
 */

// BETTER
resolve: {
    theResolvedResult: function(theService){
         return theService.theAsyncCall().then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
            return result;
         },function catchHandler(errMsg){
            console.log(errMsg);
            //return errMsg;
            //IMPORTANT re-throw error
            throw errMsg;
         });
     }
```

It is important to re-throw the error in the catch handler. Otherwise the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises) converts the rejected promise to a fulfilled promise. This is similar to the way a [try...catch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) works in vanilla JavaScript.

The [$watch method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) take a function as its first argument:

```
/* HACKY
$scope.$state=$state;
$scope.$watch('$state.$current.locals.globals.theResolvedResult', function (result) {
  $scope.aValue = result.aValue;
});
*/

//BETTER
//$scope.$state=$state;
//$scope.$watch('$state.$current.locals.globals.theResolvedResult',
$scope.$watch(
  function () {
    return $state.$current.locals.globals.theResolvedResult;
},
  function (result) {
    if (result) {
        $scope.aValue = result.aValue;
    };
});
```

When the first argument of the [$watch method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) is a string, it evaluates it as an [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) using `$scope` as its context. Since the `$state` service is not a property of `$scope` a function should be used instead.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful advice!

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to avoid the `$watch` hack in the first place. Making sure that the value is good should happen in the Service, or at the very least in the `resolve`.

Check out [this Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/9gP6Tdoc2S3UeblY3dFD/) for a demo of how `resolve` should work.

The general idea is that `resolve` has one job; to make sure that the data is ready when we want it. The [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) has a few examples on how `ui.router` handles `resolve` resolutions. They're a little limited, but generally show that "good" results are expected. Error handling is ultimately left up to your own choice.

Enjoy!